# Is timestamp function not supported in HCL2?

Tags: hcl, nomad, hashicorp

I am trying to get the current day and put in a local

```
locals {
  current_day = formatdate("DD/MM/YYYY", timestamp())
}
```

but a I get this error  `Call to unknown function; There is no function named "timestamp".`
Is timestamp function not supported in HCL2 anymore?
Is there any other way to get the current day?

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me in the current version of HCL as of May 2022.

It appears that was not possible/was a bug in the version of HCL you were using. Here is a GitHub issue that few mentions functions not working in variables at the time:

- https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/9430